# HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure - .net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-8

Receiving error "HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure" when deploying to hosted provider's IIS.  Works fine locally and worked fine until recently
. 
My dotnet version is 2.2.300.

Is there any type of logs/info that I can request to find out the root cause of the issue?

Comment: At least run a report and attach it to this question, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 2):

To troubleshoot, you can run `dotnet` command against deployed dll in the hosting machine.[image]

```
> dotnet MyDllxxx.Web.dll
```

If the issue is a missing expected version as shown on the screenshot, you can then download the correct version and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are targeting multiple version of the .NET SDK in your projects, Make sure to target .NET 2.2 and rebuild, it will solve the issue.

Also make sure go to NuGet Manager for Solution and consolidate all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

add a global.json file with .net core version.

```
{
   "sdk": {
      "version": "2.2.402"
   }
}
```

> global.json can be placed anywhere in the file hierarchy. The CLI searches upward from the project directory for the first global.json it finds. You control which projects a given global.json applies to by its place in the file system. The .NET CLI searches for a global.json file iteratively navigating the path upward from the current working directory. The first global.json file found specifies the version used. If that version is installed, that version is used. If the SDK specified in the global.json is not found, the .NET CLI rolls forward to the latest SDK installed. Roll-forward is the same as the default behavior, when no global.json file is found.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection